# Resource by device type?

Tags: android, resources

Following [official documentation about using resources in android project](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html) , i can't find any information about handling resources by device type. For example - Samsung, Lenovo, HTC. I explain why i need this. On Samsung device sPen SDK is supported, but on Lenovo - not. So i need different layout for different device types.

Note. I understood that i can handle this options on code level, but i want to know is there any way to handle this situation on resource level.

Comment: **"i want to know is there any way to handle this situation on resource level."** : No, it's not possible - there are far too many manufacturers and devices out there and resources aren't meant to be used in that way. You are restricted to handling it at a code level as you say.

Comment: @Squonk maybe i can choose some another **res/** folder when i will make apk for different devices?

Comment: If you need a different layout then it seems it would make sense to just do a test for device capabilities and use a different layout XML when calling `setContentView(...)`.